# Why group header in xamarin forms list view isn't visible in release mode?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view with group header that isn't visible in release mode, just in debug mode.

Here's a screenshot from debug mode
[image: Debug mode]

Here's a screenshot from release mode
[image: Release mode]

I've tried to update NuGet extensions, android version, even tried to build the app in another phone but nothing works.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" 
                  HasUnevenRows="True" 
                  ItemSelected="MyList_ItemSelected"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="True">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

...

</ListView>
```

CS:

```
var groupedCompanies = companies.Where(x => !x.status.StartsWith("1") &&  
                                            !x.status.StartsWith("9"))
                                .GroupBy(x => x.status);

ObservableCollection<IGrouping<string, Company>> collection = new ObservableCollection<IGrouping<string, Company>>(groupedCompanies);

myList.ItemsSource = collection;
```

I expect to build the app in release mode with the group headers visible as the debug mode headers and have no idea about what could be causing the problem.

Comment: Have you check all of the project properties & made sure all options (other than defining DEBUG constant) are the same for both Release & Debug configurations

Comment: What is the Mono Linker Behavior set to in your release configuration? If it is anything other than `Don't Link`, set it to `Don't Link` as a test and re-test a release/ad-hoc build. If that fixes the problem, update you question with those facts...

Comment: And also, are you sure in release mode the data is the same and correctly filled?

Comment: Thank you SushiHangover it was linking sdk assemblies.

Comment: @RuanMolinari If the fixed the problem, you should look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker in order to find which classes/methods/properties are being stripped (your APK is quite large now with the linker turned off, but if you do not care...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on Android, after implementing my own grouping it worked fine.

```
public class MyGrouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
   public K Key { get; private set; }

   public MyGrouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
   {
     Key = key;
     foreach (var item in items)
        this.Items.Add(item);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem just now. The issue is the `Key` property on `IGrouping` or its implementation is being linked away.

In my code I did something like:

```
bool falseFlag = false;
if (falseFlag)
{
    Console.WriteLine(groupedCompanies.First().Key);
}
```

And that was enough to fix the issue. Disabling linking isn't a great option if it can be avoided.